# Java spring + hibernate interface (DAO) <bean>

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

This is a very simple spring + hibernate example. What am I doing wrong here?

DTO:

```
package com.xx.dto;

import java.util.Date;
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class UserData {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "user_firstname")
    private String firstname;

    @Column(name = "user_lastname")
    private String lastname;

    @Column(name = "user_sex")
    private String sex;

    @Column(name = "user_birthdate")
    private Date birthDate;

    @Column(name = "user_email")
    private String email;

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFirstname() {
        return firstname;
    }

    public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
        this.firstname = firstname;
    }

    public String getLastname() {
        return lastname;
    }

    public void setLastname(String lastname) {
        this.lastname = lastname;
    }

    public String getSex() {
        return sex;
    }

    public void setSex(String sex) {
        this.sex = sex;
    }

    public Date getBirthDate() {
        return birthDate;
    }

    public void setBirthDate(Date birthDate) {
        this.birthDate = birthDate;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
}
```

DAO interface:

```
package com.xx.dao;

import java.util.List;
import com.provisori.dto.UserData;

public interface UserDataDao {

    void saveUser(UserData user);

    void deleteUser(String key);

    void updateUser(UserData user);

    List<UserData> listUser();
}
```

DAO implementation:

```
package com.xx.imp;

import java.util.List;
import org.hibernate.Criteria;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.criterion.Restrictions;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
import com.provisori.dao.UserDataDao;
import com.provisori.dto.UserData;

public class UserDataImp implements UserDataDao{

    @Autowired
    SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Transactional
    @Override
    public void saveUser(UserData user) {
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(user);
    }

    @Transactional
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public List<UserData> listUser() {
        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
                .createCriteria(UserData.class).list();
    }

    @Transactional
    @Override
    public void updateUser(UserData user) {
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().update(user);

    }

    @Transactional
    public UserData getUser(String key) {
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(UserData.class);
        criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("key", key));
        return (UserData) criteria.uniqueResult();
    }

    @Transactional
    @Override
    public void deleteUser(String key) {
        UserData user = getUser(key);
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().delete(user);
    }
}
```

spring.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd">

    <!-- Needed for Autowiring -->
    <context:annotation-config />

    <!-- MySQL DataSource -->
    <bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource">
        <property name="driverClass" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/xx" />
        <property name="user" value="root" />
        <property name="password" value="" />
    </bean>

    <!-- Hibernate SessionFactory -->
    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>
                <value>com.provisori.dto.UserData</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <value>
                hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update
                hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
            </value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <!-- Transaction Management -->
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager" />
    <bean id="txManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>

    <!-- Java Bean -->
    <bean id="userDataDao" class="com.provisori.imp.UserDataImp" />

</beans>
```

Main.class

```
package com.provisori.dto;
import org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

import com.provisori.dao.UserDataDao;
import com.provisori.imp.UserDataImp;

public class TestMain {

   public static void main(String[] args) {

      // Construct the spring application context
      AbstractApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring.xml");

      // Register hook to shutdown Spring gracefully
      // See http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-shutdown
      context.registerShutdownHook();

      // Get the business bean from context
      UserDataDao dao = (UserDataImp) context.getBean("userDataDao");

      // Create simple property objects
      UserData user = new UserData();
      user.setFirstname("firstnameTest");
      user.setLastname("lastnameTest");
      dao.saveUser(user);
   }
}
```

result

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: $Proxy13 cannot be cast to com.provisori.imp.UserDataImp
    at com.provisori.dto.TestMain.main(TestMain.java:21)

Comment: It seems that you modified the original question, source code and your problem. That's not good as answers can no longer be adequate.

Comment: I updated my answer to the new result you posted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error is a good indicator — interfaces can't be instantiated. Use the bean implementation:

```
<bean id="userDataDao" class="com.provisori.imp.UserDataImp">
```

Comment: Main: UserDataDao dao = (UserDataDao) context.getBean("userDataDao");
spring.xml: <bean id="userDataDao" class="com.provisori.imp.UserDataImp" />

Comment: @Fawi That's what I suggested. Changing cast. You need to study Java and Spring as I think you don't know what you are doing.

Answer (score 3):

You can't instantiate interface.

Your code:

```
<!-- Business Bean -->
<bean id="userDataDao" class="com.provisori.dao.UserDataDao">  
    <property name="userDataImp" ref="userDataImp" />  
</bean>
<bean id="userDataImp" class="com.provisori.imp.UserDataImp" />
```

You need to remove the first bean called `userDataDao`. I recommend reading Spring Docs as you probably don't know/understand Spring IoC container basics.

Documentation is your friend: [READ](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/)

EDITED **After you changed source code, stacktrace in your question:**

Your code:

```
UserDataDao dao = (UserDataImp) context.getBean("userDataDao");
```

try changing it to:

```
UserDataDao dao = (UserDataDao) context.getBean("userDataDao");
```

Your current error is caused by Spring-generated proxy class that is not a subclass of `UserDataImp` but it implements the same interface. So it cannot be cast to your concrete implementation. Instead you need to user interface.

Comment: If I delete  the first bean called userDataDao, then how can I call context.getBean("userDataDao"); ? getBean("userDataDao") does not exist

Comment: You need to use name of your bean to get it from application context. You are changing names in your question so it's possible part of my answer is not up-to-date. Your current code: `<bean id="userDataDao" class="com.provisori.imp.UserDataImp" />` You used name `userDataDao`.